# Crud problem between my web site and googlesheets

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, google-api

I'm creating a crud in HTML, JAVASCRIPT for showing editing and deleting googlesheets entries.

After setting all my connection parameters, I always have the response "error 401"

Can someone help me? (I deleted my credentials)

Here's my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Google Sheets Reader</title>
    <style>
        /* Styles for your table */
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }

        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        /* Style for the image */
        img.dalkia-logo {
            max-width: 100px; /* Ajustez la largeur maximale selon vos besoins */
            height: auto;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto; /* Centre l'image horizontalement */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f0/Logo_Dalkia.svg/langfr-210px-Logo_Dalkia.svg.png" alt="Logo Dalkia" class="dalkia-logo">
    <table id="dataTable">
        <!-- Table content will be populated dynamically -->
    </table>
    <button id="addButton">Ajouter une ligne</button>

    <script>
        const spreadsheetId = '';
        const apiKey = '';
        const sheetName = '';
        let data; // Stockage des données récupérées

        // Function to fetch data from Google Sheets
        function fetchData() {
            fetch(`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${spreadsheetId}/values/${sheetName}?key=${apiKey}`)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(responseData => {
                    data = responseData; // Stockage des données récupérées dans la variable globale
                    const dataTable = document.getElementById('dataTable');
                    dataTable.innerHTML = '';

                    data.values.forEach(row => {
                        const newRow = dataTable.insertRow();
                        row.forEach(cellValue => {
                            const newCell = newRow.insertCell();
                            newCell.textContent = cellValue;
                        });

                        // Add Edit and Delete buttons to each row
                        const editButton = document.createElement('button');
                        editButton.textContent = 'Éditer';
                        editButton.addEventListener('click', () => editRow(row));

                        const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
                        deleteButton.textContent = 'Supprimer';
                        deleteButton.addEventListener('click', () => deleteRow(row));

                        newRow.appendChild(editButton);
                        newRow.appendChild(deleteButton);
                    });
                })
                .catch(error => console.error(error));
        }

        // Function to edit a row
        function editRow(rowData) {
            const updatedData = prompt('Entrez les nouvelles données séparées par des virgules:', rowData.join(', '));
            if (updatedData !== null) {
                const newData = updatedData.split(', ');
                const rowIndex = data.values.indexOf(rowData);
                data.values[rowIndex] = newData;

                // Update the Google Sheets data
                updateGoogleSheets(data.values);

                // Refresh the table
                fetchData();
            }
        }

        // Function to delete a row
        function deleteRow(rowData) {
            if (confirm('Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer cette ligne ?')) {
                const rowIndex = data.values.indexOf(rowData);
                data.values.splice(rowIndex, 1);

                // Update the Google Sheets data
                updateGoogleSheets(data.values);

                // Refresh the table
                fetchData();
            }
        }

        // Function to update data in Google Sheets
        function updateGoogleSheets(updatedData) {
            const requestBody = {
                values: updatedData
            };

            fetch(`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${spreadsheetId}/values/${sheetName}?valueInputOption=RAW&key=${apiKey}`, {
                method: 'PUT',
                body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    console.log('Données mises à jour avec succès');
                } else {
                    console.error('Erreur lors de la mise à jour des données');
                }
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(error));
        }

        // Add event listener to the "Ajouter une ligne" button
        document.getElementById('addButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
            // Implement logic to add a new row here
        });

        // Fetch data when the page loads
        fetchData();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the answer when I try to delete a line:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()
> (index):118 Erreur lors de la mise à jour des données
> (anonyme) @ (index):118
> (index):107
> PUT https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1tUabe1-BO5iVMICKJ3dUxu5lCrHD6tIhueys9YUnFe0/values/R%C3%A9ponses%20au%20formulaire%201?valueInputOption=RAW&key=AIzaSyBvmaKwkRf_nRZbql5Vuib53cJuUCgBssA 401 (Unauthorized)
> updateGoogleSheets @ (index):107
> editRow @ (index):80
> (anonyme) @ (index):58
> (index):118 Erreur lors de la mise à jour des données
> (anonyme) @ (index):118
> Promise.then (asynchrone)
> updateGoogleSheets @ (index):114
> editRow @ (index):80
> (anonyme) @ (index):58

Comment: 401 is `Unauthorized` - see https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/auth-overview - note Authentication (who is making the request) isn't the same as Authorization (what what resources the requestor can access). Basically you have a permissions issue - i.e. the authenticated user isn't authorized to delete from that sheet.

Comment: If your Spreadsheet is publicly shared, the values of the Spreadsheet can be retrieved by the API key with the GET method. But, unfortunately, in the current stage, the API key can be used only in the GET method. In your showing script, it seems that you are using the API key for requesting the PUT method. I guessed that this might be the reason for your current issue. If you want to remove this issue, please use the access token instead of the API key.